# Проверка состояния checkbox

Tags: javascript

Как можно проверить состояние checkbox-а после перезагрузки страницы с помощью javascript ?

Ести js функция:

```
function reload(){
     location.reload();
}
```

и checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all" onClick="reload()"/>View all
```

как мне проверить состояние после такой перезагрузки?

Comment: Какое еще состояние?

Comment: Под состоянием вы понимаете checked? или disabled?

Comment: А какое состояние может еще иметь, стоит галочка или нет.

Comment: после перезагрузки состояние сбросится.

Comment: @eicto, не обязательно, если отправлен через форму на эту же страницу, то не сбросится.

Comment: через форму я знаю как сделать а вот без формы меня интересует как проверить.

Comment: @dimka3210 , при location.reload() сбросится. просто сбросится в начальное состояние.

Comment: @scalpel когда вы собрались проверять ?

Comment: Вам уже дали ответ document.getElementsByName('all')[0].checked

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Answer (score 2):

#### Без jQuery:

```
var element = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');    

if (element.checked) {
    doSomething();
}
```

#### С jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: К JQuery, я бы еще добавил  if ( $(this).is(":checked") )

Comment: да. я видимо оппечатался. prop('checked') хотел написать. По сути это аналог Вашего кода, только отработает функция быстрее

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener('change', function () {
  var chk = event.target
  
  if (chk.tagName === 'INPUT' && chk.type === 'checkbox') {
    console.log("%s %s %s", chk.name, chk.value, chk.checked)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type=checkbox name=a value=1>
<input type=checkbox name=a value=2>
<input type=checkbox name=a value=3>
<input type=checkbox name=a value=4>
<input type=checkbox name=a value=5>

<br>

<input type=checkbox name=b value=1>
<input type=checkbox name=b value=2>
<input type=checkbox name=b value=3>
<input type=checkbox name=b value=4>
<input type=checkbox name=b value=5>
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно так:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all">View all

<script>
    var chck = document.querySelector('input');

    if (localStorage.status !== undefined) {
      chck.checked = parseInt(localStorage.status);
    }

    chck.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      localStorage.status = e.target.checked ? 1 : 0;
      reload();
    });

    function reload(){
      location.reload();
    }
  </script>
```